# Cannot use modal in a dropdown menu element in angular strap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-strap

I use dropdown menu for bootstrap and when click on one of the elements it suppose to show [angular-strap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#) modal but it doesn't show up

here's my code

```
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
    <li><a class="link" bs-modal="solrSettingsModal" data-template="solrSettings.html" ng-click="$scope.type='default-ts'"><i class="icon-time"></i> Time-series dashboard </a></li>
    <li><a class="link" bs-modal="solrSettingsModal" data-template="solrSettings.html" ng-click="$scope.type='default-nts'"><i class="icon-th-large"></i> Non time-series dashboard </a></li>
  </ul>
```

I tried to do some debug and get the following

when I remove `dropdown-menu` css class it works fine so what's the reason for that?

there's an [issue on github](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/4615) talking about that but the propsoed solution didn't work for me